# Identify the sample points in the events $A \cup B$

Tags: probability

A pair of fair dice is tossed. Events $A$ and $B$ are defined as follows :

$A$: (The sum of the numbers on the dice is $3$)
$B$: (At least one of the dice shows a $2$)

Identify the sample points in the event $A\cup B$

A) $\{(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)\}$

B) $\{(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)(2,6),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)\}$

C) $\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$

D) $\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)\}$

How do I solve?

Comment: Can you list the sample points that are $A$? What about the sample points that are in $B$? That’s the obvious place to start.

Comment: The union $A\cup B$ is the set of all elements in A or B (*including* those in A and B).

Answer (score 2):

Since the dice are both fair and are rolled together, we can say without loss of generality that $(n_1,n_2)$ is equivalent to $(n_2,n_1).$

First identify the sample points in $A$: $\{x+y=3; 1\leq x,y \leq 6\}.$ This is the set $\{(1,2)\}.$ There are no other points in $A$, since you cannot roll a zero and order does not matter.

Now identify the sample points in $B$: $\{x=2 \mbox{ or } y=2; 1\leq x,y \leq 6 \}.$ This is the set $\{(2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6)\}.$ Notice that $A \subseteq B.$

Now the union of these two sets, $A \cup B$, contains every point in each set. Since $A$ is contained in $B$, the union is equal to $B$. So the answer  should be $\{(1,2), (2,2), (2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)\}$ which is answer A).

Answer (score 0):

$A = \{2, 1\}, \{1, 2\}$
$B =$ all with one or two $2$. So $A \subset B$ and $A \cup B = B$, it's the answer D.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
I am giving sample points of $B$ you calculate for $A$.
As you have 2 in atleast 1 die it may appear in the 1st die or in the 2nd die i.e it will be $\{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(1,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)\}$.